# Is there a specific terminology for numbers which are nontrivial multiples of triangular numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, terminology, integers, oeis

(Note: Please see this [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3283646) for the motivation.)

A number $T$ is said to be *triangular* if it could be written in the form
$$T=\frac{n(n+1)}{2},$$
where $n$ is a positive integer.

Here is my question:

> Is there a specific terminology for numbers which are nontrivial multiples of triangular numbers?

That is, is there a specific name for numbers $T'$ which are of the form
$$T' = dT = d\cdot\bigg(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\bigg),$$
for some integer $d > 1$?

I tried searching for the relevant sequence in OEIS, but all I am seeing are references to $T'$ being triangular as well.

Comment: Is there any motivation to this question? You can take any known sequence $a_n$ of positive integers and consider $S = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : k = d \cdot a_j \ \text{for} \ d \in \mathbb{N}_{>1}, j \in \mathbb{N}\}$. In general, this set won't be well known, or even have a name.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, thank you for your comment.  Please see this [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3283646) for the motivation.

Comment: Do you allow $n=1$? If so, then every integer greater than or equal to $2$ is one of these numbers, right?

Comment: @MarkS.: $n$ is *any* positive integer (i.e. it is not fixed).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer based on the confirmation in the comment.

- Note that if $T'>1$, then taking $d=T'$ and $n=1$ (so that
  $T=1*2/2=1$) works.
- Also, since $d>1$, $T'=1$ is impossible.
- And since $n,d\ge1$, $T'<1$ is impossible as well.

Therefore, a name for the possible values of $T'$ is "**integers greater than 1**".